Prove that $\lfloor\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor$ if $n>0$ is an integer

If $n$ is a positive integer prove that $\lfloor\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor$.

I started proving the the special case when $n$ or $n+1$ is a perfect square and the statement hold. Now I'm trying something more general. To do that I found some bounds for $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}$:
$$(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2 = n+n+1+2\sqrt{n(n+1)} = 2n+1 + 2\sqrt{n^2+n}$$
where, if $n\geq 1$, $$\sqrt{n^2+n}<\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}=\sqrt{(n+1)^2}=n+1 \;\;\;\text{and  }\;\;\;\sqrt{n^2+n}>\sqrt{n^2}=n$$
So i found that
$$4n+1<(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2<4n+3$$
$$\sqrt{4n+1}<\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{4n+3}$$
$$\lfloor\sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor\leq\lfloor\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor\leq\lfloor\sqrt{4n+3}\rfloor$$
Now I'm very tempted to use the fact that a perfect square cannot be of the form $4n+2$ or $4n+3$ to say that $\lfloor\sqrt{4n+3}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor$ and conclude my proof but I'm not sure that this is correct.
Can you give me some hint?

Your argument that "a perfect square cannot be of the form $4n+2$ or $4n+3$" is indeed sufficient to imply $\lfloor\sqrt{4n+3}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor$, since the square of an integer is an integer and so it means that can be no integer strictly between $\sqrt{4n+1}$ and $\sqrt{4n+4}$
